How can we add Logs in TestRigor each step?
Not able find any Log related AI command
I have tried Log,Note,Comment but failed to detect as valid comment. That log should be customizable like I can enter actual and expected results in my way. It should be same as Log4j from Java.

There is no such thing, only "Auto-heal reusable rule with AI" is available.
https://i.sstatic.net/AJKTS4H8.png
